# How to show gif image in ImageView in android?

Tags: android, image, gif

I tried Picaso library, but it is not showing gif image. I am getting images with json. 
I tried following code :-

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load( stationWithState.station.getLogo()).transform(transformation).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.stationImageView[i]);
```

please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok after doing google I found out a library which will help  in showing gif image from json [link](https://github.com/koush/ion)

```
Ion.with(viewHolder.stationImageView[i])
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .fitCenter()
                        .load(stationWithState.station.getLogo());
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageView iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

GlideApp.with(this).load("your_url").into(iv);

Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)